# local host authentication request

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, localhost, connection-refused

[Authentication request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnxp8.png)

I am actually learning nodejs in visual studio. So while running a sample code(http module-"Helloworld") and when I try to run localhost for example-http://localhost:8080/ in any browser it requests for username and password.

I am not sure what details has to be updated. Please help on how to resolve this authentication error.

Comment: can you share what code are you trying to run ?

Comment: Thanks for the response.

var http = require('http');

http.createServer(functi,
on (req, res) {
  // add a HTTP header:
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write('Hello World!');
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);

Comment: I don't think, above code should behave like your said problem does. You can have a look at this https://codesandbox.io/s/node-http-server-node.
Also, I think, you have some other thing running at 8080